# jQuery mobile Listview overflow not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this HTML page. (I use jQuery mobile 1.3.1)

It should be something like a little chat-window.
The problem I have is that, when you look at the `<li>` elements, this `<ul data-role="listview">` element should be scrollable. 
But, for some reason it simply isn't scrollable, because the content seems to be hidden behind the footer `<div>`, which should not be the case.

I have the following HTML markup:

(without the line-breaks within a tag, thats just so you guys can read this better)

```
 <div data-role="page" id="chat">
         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <a href="#clickAndChat" data-role="button" data-inline="true" 
            data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse" 
            data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-icon-alt" data-theme="c">Back</a>
            <h1 id="headerPage1">Andi (Fake)    (50m)</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content" data-role="main" >                
            <ul data-role="listview" id="chatContent" style="overflow-y: scroll">
                <li>Satz A von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz B von mir</li>
                <li>Satz C von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz A von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz B von mir</li>
                <li>Satz C von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz A von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz B von mir</li>
                <li>Satz C von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz A von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz B von mir</li>
                <li>Satz C von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz A von Andi</li>
                <li>Satz B von mir</li>
                <li>Satz C von Andi</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <input type="text" name="chatText" id="chatText" placeholder="Type here...">
            <button id="sendChatText" data-icon="check" class="ui-icon-alt"
             data-theme="c">Send</button>               
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ul` actually is scrollable. The reason that you are not seeing the scrollbar is because the elements haven't exceeded the maximum height. When you limit the `ul` height and the elements can no longer be contained, then the scrollbar will appear.

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v31zL5y1/).

Comment: thank you Alex!
The problem is, this is going to be on mobile. So a fixed height with a px or em value wouldn't really do the job. (different device heights etc.)
Thing is, I thought there would be an option to limit the content to the div with data-role=main. 
Any advice on that?

Comment: ok when I test this on my mobile, the `<ul data-role="listview">` is indeed scrollable by touch. but it still won't show a scrollbar. I'll come back when I figured out.

Comment: Ok I think @Alex answer is the closest I will get, so thank you again.